# Parsing HTML in an email with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have a form I am using to simply capture a name and email from a user. When the user submits the form an email is then fired to the specified recipient containing a link.

I had this all working but realised I needed to add a html footer to the email which was originally being read as plain text.

After doing some digging I have now tried to set the footer to read as html ,but the email no longer sends. I am not a php developer.

My question is have I missed something or am I just way off?

```
<?php

// configure
$from = 'Ether Solutions Sales <email@domain.co.uk>';
$sendTo = $_POST['remail'];
$subject = "test email";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$okMessage = 'your message has been sent successfully, please ask the recipient to check their inbox';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";


// Create email headers

$headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// Compose a simple HTML email message

$message = '<html><body>';

$message .= '<p style="margin-bottom:30px;">regards dave</p>';

$message .= '<a href="http://www.domain.co.uk" title="link to domain website">www.domain.co.uk</a>';
$message .= '<p style="font-color:blue;">Office Tel: 0844 000 000</p>';
$message .= '<p style="font-color:blue;">Mobile: 0000 000 0000</p>';
$message .= '<p style="font-color:blue;">Technical Support: 0845 000 0000</p>
';
$message .= '<p style="font-color:blue; font-weight:bold;">Some tagline here</p>
';
$message .= '<img src="imageurl/test.png" alt="sample alt tag"/>';

$message .= '</body></html>';


// let's do the sending

try
{   
    $emailText = "{$name} you have been sent an electronic document to be signed.\nTo view your document please click the following link URL: /www.domain.com";


    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, $message, $headers, "From: " . $from);

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

Comment: I suppose you need to check what are the arguments of `mail` function.

Comment: Hi, it would be better to use PHPMailer library that wraps mail function. See this: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and got this warning:

> PHP Warning:  mail() expects at most 5 parameters, 6 given in /home/ruemercc/public_html/lab/email2/mail.php on line 47

I would suggest you use PHPMailer library found here [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

. It will allow you to even send bulk emails(Which I think will be an added advantege in your case).
Have fun coding

Comment: Thanks Mwangi, I have merged both the $message and $emailText and the html email now sends although I now have to figure out how I am going to parse the clients $name as $message is being used with html

Comment: Ok. Do you mean  contatinating the $name into $message?

Comment: $message = '<html><body>';

$message .= '<p style="margin-bottom:30px;">regards '.$name.'</p>';

$message .= '<a href="http://www.domain.co.uk" title="link to domain website">www.domain.co.uk</a>';
$message .= '<p style="font-color:blue;">Office Tel: 0844 000 000</p>';
$message .= '<p style="font-color:blue;">Mobile: 0000 000 0000</p>';
$message .= '<p style="font-color:blue; font-weight:bold;">Some tagline here</p>
';
$message .= '<img src="imageurl/test.png" alt="sample alt tag"/>';

$message .= '</body></html>';

Comment: Ie regards '.$name.'

Comment: Originally I had the $emailText variable contained within double quotes as it contained effectively just text which allowed me to add the $name variable via the {$name} approach. 

Now I have combined both into the $message variable which contains html and so I am using single quotes. I would like to add the $name variable at the start of the message to include the recipients name. 

Before replying I had tried .$name.which didn't work. I now have it working using $name. followed by the html string :)

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction and for your patience today :)

Comment: I have been away for a while, but I think you can try Twig https://twig.symfony.com/, we can use it to pass the variables to a view.

Answer (score 1):

Your call of the `mail()` wrong. You are setting the parameters not correct.

Take a look in the [PHP Manual for `mail()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mail.php).

**From the php manual**

```
mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

Your code `mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, $message, $headers, "From: " . $from)` uses `message` as `$additional_headers` which is wrong.

You have to merge your `$message` with the `$emailText`.

Comment: Thanks bro, I merged the two as suggested however I am now presented with a problem. Yes the email is sending as html which is great. But originally $emailText was also parsing the name variable at the start of the string. 

Can this still be achieved as $message is being used with html?